# How to make the overflow show up on my website (I know of overflow attribute)..?

Tags: html, css

This is for a online chat, here is a summary of my client-side code:

```css
.msgln {
    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
    padding: 0.5%;
    border: 3px solid #eee;
}

#chatbox {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox" style="list-style: none;">
  <li>
    <div class="msgln" data-user="Example">(current date)<b>Example</b>: <br/>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

The scroll doesn't show up inside `#chatbox`, just on the entire page, meaning you have to scroll up to the top to see the page header (and signout button), then back down to the bottom to see new messages.

Comment: Use `overflow:auto`

Comment: That is already in there, pay attention to the CSS.

Comment: Why `class="chatbox"` but css as `#chatbox`?

Comment: Sorry, it's `id="chatbox"` in the HTML, I wrote it wrong on here.

Comment: @SwxtchCode, i fixed it already

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're going to use `<li>`, the items should be wrapped in `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment above, you need to use the `<ul>` tag as a parent for the `<li>` tags.

`#chatbox` already has a `overflow: auto` rule as well as a **50% height**. And to show you clearly, I created some `<li>` tags and set the `height: 100vh` for the `<body>` tag.

Is this what you wanted?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.msgln {
    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
    padding: 0.5%;
    border: 3px solid #eee;
}

#chatbox {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul id="chatbox" style="list-style: none;">
  <li>
    <div class="msgln" data-user="Example">(current date)<b>Example</b>: <br/>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="msgln" data-user="Example">(current date)<b>Example</b>: <br/>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="msgln" data-user="Example">(current date)<b>Example</b>: <br/>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="msgln" data-user="Example">(current date)<b>Example</b>: <br/>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="msgln" data-user="Example">(current date)<b>Example</b>: <br/>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="msgln" data-user="Example">(current date)<b>Example</b>: <br/>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="msgln" data-user="Example">(current date)<b>Example</b>: <br/>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="msgln" data-user="Example">(current date)<b>Example</b>: <br/>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="msgln" data-user="Example">(current date)<b>Example</b>: <br/>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @SwxtchCode, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce your problem but have you tried `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work. I'm going to work on possibly re-writing the code later today, the code itself is a bit over-complicated.